# Read Firebase Firestore document if it document's property matches a request property

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm sure this is a popular question but I can't find the question/answer!

- **Aim**: Read Firestore if the currently logged-in user's uid matches a document's uid.
- **Current result**: I get an error when trying to read.
  `Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Here's my Firestore rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /cars/{document} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == document.uid;
    }
   
  }
}
```

Here's a sample data:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refer to document data in rules, the syntax is like this:

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
```

This will work when the client performs a `get()` of the individual document, and they are signed in with a UID that matches the uid field of the document.

I suggest reviewing the documentation on [authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) and [data validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).